# Multi-Target and Multi-Class prediction

Tags: tensorflow

I am relatively new to machine learning as well as tensorflow. I would like to train the data so that predictions with 2 targets and multiple classes could be made. Is this something that can be done? I was able to implement the algorithm for 1 target but don't know how I need to do it for a second target as well.

An example dataset:
    DayOfYear Temperature Flow Visibility

```
316 8   1   4
285 -1  1   4
326 8   2   5
323 -1  0   3
10  7   3   6
62  8   0   3
56  8   1   4
347 7   2   5
363 7   0   3
77  7   3   6
1   7   1   4
308 -1  2   5
364 7   3   6
```

If I train (DayOfYear Temperature Flow) I can predict the Visibility quite well. But I need to predict Flow as well somehow. I am pretty sure that Flow will influence Visibility so I am not sure how to go with that.

This is the implementation that I have

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import urllib

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Data sets
TRAINING = "/ml_baetterich_learn.csv"
TEST = "/ml_baetterich_test.csv"
VALIDATION = "/ml_baetterich_validation.csv"

def main():

  # Load datasets.
  training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
      filename=TRAINING,
      target_dtype=np.int,
      features_dtype=np.int,
      target_column=-1)
  test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
      filename=TEST,
      target_dtype=np.int,
      features_dtype=np.int,
      target_column=-1)
  validation_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
      filename=VALIDATION,
      target_dtype=np.int,
      features_dtype=np.int,
      target_column=-1)

  # Specify that all features have real-value data
  feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=3)]

  # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
  classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                              hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                              n_classes=9,
                                              model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
  # Define the training inputs
  def get_train_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(training_set.data)
    y = tf.constant(training_set.target)

    return x, y

  # Fit model.
  classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=4000)

  # Define the test inputs
  def get_test_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(test_set.data)
    y = tf.constant(test_set.target)

    return x, y

  # Define the test inputs
  def get_validation_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(validation_set.data)
    y = tf.constant(validation_set.target)

    return x, y

  # Evaluate accuracy.
  accuracy_test_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs,
                                       steps=1)["accuracy"]

  accuracy_validation_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_validation_inputs,
                                       steps=1)["accuracy"]

  print ("\nValidation Accuracy: {0:0.2f}\nTest Accuracy: {1:0.2f}\n".format(accuracy_validation_score,accuracy_test_score))

  # Classify two new flower samples.
  def new_samples():
    return np.array(
      [[327,8,3],
       [47,8,0]], dtype=np.float32)

  predictions = list(classifier.predict_classes(input_fn=new_samples))

  print(
      "New Samples, Class Predictions:    {}\n"
      .format(predictions))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 7):

## Option 1: multi-headed model

You could use a multi-headed DNNEstimator model. This treats Flow and Visibility as two separate softmax classification targets, each with their own set of classes. I had to modify the `load_csv_without_header` helper function to support multiple targets (which could be cleaner, but is not the point here - feel free to ignore its details).

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
import csv
import collections

num_flow_classes = 4
num_visib_classes = 7

Dataset = collections.namedtuple('Dataset', ['data', 'target'])

def load_csv_without_header(fn, target_dtype, features_dtype, target_columns):
    with gfile.Open(fn) as csv_file:
        data_file = csv.reader(csv_file)
        data = []
        targets = {
            target_cols: []
            for target_cols in target_columns.keys()
        }
        for row in data_file:
            cols = sorted(target_columns.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
            for target_col_name, target_col_i in cols:
                targets[target_col_name].append(row.pop(target_col_i))
            data.append(np.asarray(row, dtype=features_dtype))

        targets = {
            target_col_name: np.array(val, dtype=target_dtype)
            for target_col_name, val in targets.items()
        }
        data = np.array(data)
        return Dataset(data=data, target=targets)

feature_columns = [
    tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=1),
    tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2),
]
head = tf.contrib.learn.multi_head([
    tf.contrib.learn.multi_class_head(
        num_flow_classes, label_name="Flow", head_name="Flow"),
    tf.contrib.learn.multi_class_head(
        num_visib_classes, label_name="Visibility", head_name="Visibility"),
])
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNEstimator(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
    model_dir="iris_model",
    head=head,
)

def get_input_fn(filename):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = load_csv_without_header(
            fn=filename,
            target_dtype=np.int,
            features_dtype=np.int,
            target_columns={"Flow": 2, "Visibility": 3}
        )
        x = tf.constant(dataset.data)
        y = {k: tf.constant(v) for k, v in dataset.target.items()}
        return x, y
    return input_fn

classifier.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn("tmp_train.csv"), steps=4000)
res = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_input_fn("tmp_test.csv"), steps=1)

print("Validation:", res)
```

## Option 2: multi-labeled head

If you keep your CSV data separated by commas, and keep the last column for all the classes a row might have (separated by some token such as space), you can use the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

all_classes = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

def k_hot(classes_col, all_classes, delimiter=' '):
    table = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
        mapping=tf.constant(all_classes)
    )
    classes = tf.string_split(classes_col, delimiter)
    ids = table.lookup(classes)
    num_items = tf.cast(tf.shape(ids)[0], tf.int64)
    num_entries = tf.shape(ids.indices)[0]

    y = tf.SparseTensor(
        indices=tf.stack([ids.indices[:, 0], ids.values], axis=1),
        values=tf.ones(shape=(num_entries,), dtype=tf.int32),
        dense_shape=(num_items, len(all_classes)),
    )
    y = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(y, validate_indices=False)
    return y

def feature_engineering_fn(features, labels):
    labels = k_hot(labels, all_classes)
    return features, labels

feature_columns = [
    tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=1), # DayOfYear
    tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2), # Temperature
]
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNEstimator(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
    model_dir="iris_model",
    head=tf.contrib.learn.multi_label_head(n_classes=len(all_classes)),
    feature_engineering_fn=feature_engineering_fn,
)

def get_input_fn(filename):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
            filename=filename,
            target_dtype="S100", # strings of length up to 100 characters
            features_dtype=np.int,
            target_column=-1
        )
        x = tf.constant(dataset.data)
        y = tf.constant(dataset.target)
        return x, y
    return input_fn

classifier.fit(input_fn=get_input_fn("tmp_train.csv"), steps=4000)
res = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_input_fn("tmp_test.csv"), steps=1)

print("Validation:", res)
```

We are using `DNNEstimator` with a `multi_label_head`, which uses sigmoid crossentropy rather than softmax crossentropy as a loss function. This means that each of the output units/logits are passed through the sigmoid function, which gives the likelihood of the data point belonging to that class, i.e. the classes are computed independently and are not mutually exclusive as they are with softmax crossentropy. This means that you could have between 0 and `len(all_classes)` classes set for each row in the training set and final predictions.

Also notice that the classes are represented as strings (and `k_hot` makes the conversion to token indices), so that you could use arbitrary class identifiers such as category UUIDs in e-commerce settings. If the categories in the 3rd and 4th column are different (Flow ID 1 != Visibility ID 1), you could prepend the column name to each class ID, e.g.

`316,8,flow1 visibility4
285,-1,flow1 visibility4
326,8,flow2 visibility5`

For a description of how `k_hot` works, see [my other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159133/does-tf-one-hot-supports-sparsetensor-as-indices-parameter/47657743#47657743). I decided to use `k_hot` as a separate function (rather than define it directly in `feature_engineering_fn` because it's a distinct piece of functionality, and probably TensorFlow will soon have a similar utility function.

Note that if you're now using the first two columns to predict the last two columns, your accuraccy will certainly go down, as the last two columns are highly correlated and using one of them will give you a lot of information about the other. Actually, your code was using only the 3rd column, which was kind of a cheat anyway if the goal is to predict the 3rd and 4th columns.

Comment: why temperature has dimension 2? "tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2), # Temperature" It's also a scalar, so should be dimension 1?